# How to fetch an object from a oneToMany relationship using createQuery()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

My structure is as simple as 
One user -> has many notifications

so to fetch the notifications of the logged in user 
I type this on the controller

```
$notifications = $this->getUser()->getNotifications();
```

Now I need to paginate the results but since this won't work

```
$notifications = $this->getUser()->getNotifications()->setMaxResults(2)..
```

I guess I need to use a createQuery to fetch the results?
what query would be the DQL equivalent of

`"$this->getUser()->getNotifications()"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't limit . Try slice

If you have Doctrine 2.1 you can use ->slice() on the collection:

```
 $notifications = $this->getUser()->getNotifications();    

    $result  = $notification->slice(0, 2);
```